# debian 6 - php 5.4.1 - xdebug phpize php-config --version incorrect

Tags: linux, debian, php5, debian-squeeze, xdebug

I'm quite new with Linux server management and I have a linux server with the following configuration:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.6
Codename:       squeeze
PHP version:    5.4.12-1~dotdeb.1
```

I'm trying to install xdebug and I've used the wizard on the xdebug website().

```
Output of xdebug
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.12-1
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php5/apache2
Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php5/20100525
Instructions

    Download xdebug-2.2.1.tgz
    Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.1.tgz
    Run: cd xdebug-2.2.1

    Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.

    As part of its output it should show:

    Configuring for:
    ...
    Zend Module Api No:      20100525
    Zend Extension Api No:   220100525

    If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
    Run: ./configure
    Run: make
    Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php5/20100525
    Edit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and add the line
    zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so
    Restart the webserver
```

After I followed these steps and do run `make test` I get this output:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.

Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.


=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.4.12-1~dotdeb.1
ZEND_VERSION: 2.4.0
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux debian-web-001 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64
INI actual  : /usr/lib/xdebug-2.2.1/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :  
CWD         : /usr/lib/xdebug-2.2.1
Extra dirs  : 
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================
TIME START 2013-03-10 16:16:37
=====================================================================
No tests were run.
```

As you can see I still get the same error..
Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or where to look at?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a package in Debian for this? Installing from source is rarely the right course of action.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed php 5.4 from http://packages.dotdeb.org/, so I think I cant use http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5-xdebug for installing xdebug.. Or am I wrong? PS: The xdebug on the packages page of debian is version 2.1, but PHP 5.4 is supported by xdebug >= 2.2.x

Comment: as far as I can see dotdeb's guys do not provide package with Xdebug. Why dont you use pecl to install XDebug package ? It should be quite easy.

Comment: I also tried pecl install xdebug but the same problems with phpize showed up... "Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626. The Zend Engine API ... for a later version of Xdebug.".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds, from the comments, like the specific problem that you have that's leading you to not use the existing php5-xdebug package is that you need PHP 5.4.  At this point, I would strongly recommend that you save yourself a lot of pain and just upgrade your system to Debian wheezy (currently testing).  We're about two or three months away from a release, the distribution is mostly frozen, and you'll have nearly as good of an experience as a stable release.  It's a bit scary to be on the cutting edge, but Debian wheezy effectively already has security support nearly as good as what you'd get with stable.

wheezy would give you PHP 5.4.4 and Xdebug 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to new version of php and getting it working I realised that the company I was working for source code did not work properly with this version so returned to original version then had wrong verison in php-config --version.
The new version was stored in /etc/php/5.6 (5.6.26);
The old version was stored in /etc/php5 (5.5.9Ubuntu-4.19)
Also 
The phpize returned the wrong version, found another in /usr/bin version of phpize; phpize5.

```
inform-laptop xdebug-2.4.1 # phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         xxxxxxxx
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

inform-laptop xdebug-2.4.1 # phpize5  
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
```

Then used phpize5 to follow instructions on site https://xdebug.org/wizard.php so get xdebug working.There is also a php-config5 in /user/bin

```
inform-laptop bin # php-config5 --version
5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19
```